# IntelliJ item register

Tags: java, intellij-idea, minecraft-forge

i want to code a mod with IntelliJ but i have this problem =

```
public static final RegistryObject<Item> TITAN = ITEMS.register("titan",
        ()-> new Item(new Item.Properties().group(ItemGroup.REDSTONE)));
```

on the first line "TITAN" is "never found" but i don´t know what the problem is.
Here is the Full Code=

```
 package de.andreas7bf.red_quark.core.init;

import de.andreas7bf.red_quark.Red_quark;
import net.minecraft.item.Item;
import net.minecraft.item.ItemGroup;
import net.minecraftforge.fml.RegistryObject;
import net.minecraftforge.registries.DeferredRegister;
import net.minecraftforge.registries.ForgeRegistries;

public class ItemInit {
    public static final DeferredRegister<Item> ITEMS = DeferredRegister.create(ForgeRegistries.ITEMS, Red_quark.MOD_ID);

    public static final RegistryObject<Item> TITAN = ITEMS.register("titan",
            ()-> new Item(new Item.Properties().group(ItemGroup.REDSTONE)));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

At line 13, you have made a slight mistake. It should be

```
public static final RegistryObject<Item> TITAN = ITEMS.register("titan",
    () -> new Item( new Item.Properties().tab(ItemGroup.REDSTONE)));
```

This is because the group() method does not exist anymore in Forge 1.16.x, you have to replace it with tab() method. Try it out and post the error log also :).